# character i.e. 'a' or any other letter other then 0-9 the program loops infinitely

Tags: c, input, infinite-loop

I am a beginner at programming and am making a tic tac to game in c. My problem as the title suggest is that when I input a character i.e. 'a' other then an integer i.e. 0-9 the program loops through the  while loop in main() infinitely or until it reaches the temporary limit I placed with out asking for user input. I can't for the life of me figure out what is wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TRUE    1
#define FALSE   0

void greet_players();
void draw_grid(int loc, char cur_player, char point[]);
char swap_player(char *cur_player, int *is_turn);
int player_loc();
int check_win();

int main(){
    int i;
    int is_turn;
    int loc = 0;
    char point[9];
    char cur_player;

    
    greet_players(); //greet players.
    
    for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){ point[i] = '_'; }// set the point array to '_'.

    int temp = 0;
    is_turn = TRUE;   // set the first turn to true.
    cur_player = 'X'; // set the first player before the grid is printed.
    
    while(/*!check_win()*/temp<3){ 
        swap_player(&cur_player, &is_turn); // change player for the next loop.
        if(is_turn == TRUE) { is_turn = FALSE; }
        draw_grid(loc, cur_player, point); 
        temp++;
        
    };
    
    return 0;
}
/***************************************************************************/

// Function prints out a greeting to players.
void greet_players(){   
    puts("***********************************************************************************");
    puts("Hello this is tic tac toe.");
    puts("The rules are simple: ");
    puts("#1 two players each place their pieces (X,O) on a 9x9 grid.");
    puts("#2 when a player has placed three pieces either horizontal or vertical they win.");
    puts("#3 and thats it, have fun.");
    puts("***********************************************************************************\n");
    // print the first grid empty
    puts("Tic_Tac_Toe.");
    puts("  |1|2|3|");
    puts("  |4|5|6|");
    puts("  |7|8|9|");
    puts("***********************************************************************************");
}
/***************************************************************************/

// Function draws grid.
void draw_grid(int loc, char cur_player, char point[]){
    int i, j, p;
    
    p = player_loc()-1;
    printf("%d\n", p);
    puts("Tic_Tac_Toe.");
    if(point[p] == '_'){
        point[p] = cur_player;
        for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            printf("  ");
            for(j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                printf("|%c", point[loc]);
                loc++;
            }
            puts("|");
        }
        puts("***********************************************************************************");
    }
    else{ puts("\nSpace invalid,please choose an empty Location('_')."); }
}
/***************************************************************************/

// Function gets the current players inputed locition.
int player_loc(){
    int player_loc = 0;
    scanf(" %d", &player_loc);
    
    if(player_loc >= 1 && player_loc <= 9 ){ return (player_loc); }
    else{ return (0); }
}
/***************************************************************************/

// Function changes player icon to the next icon when the current player inputs their location.
char swap_player(char *cur_player, int *is_turn){
    if(*cur_player == 'X' && *is_turn == FALSE){ 
        *cur_player = 'O';
        *is_turn = TRUE;
    }
    if(*cur_player == 'O' && *is_turn == FALSE){ 
        *cur_player = 'X';
        *is_turn = TRUE;
    }
    
    return (*cur_player);
}
/***************************************************************************/

int check_win(){ return (0); }
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the program?

Comment: `scanf(" %d", &player_loc);` only accepts integers. Any other input will be ignored and stay in the input stream. A classic source of an endless loop

Comment: You should check the return value of your `scanf()` call in `player_loc()`.  If `scanf()` it returns zero, it means that the input data didn't match the format string and so you can't rely on the value in player_loc to be anything useful or that in any way reflects what was typed.